# Error Publishing Mule JSON Logger to Anypoint Exchange

Tags: java, maven, mule, mulesoft, mule4

I am trying to publish the Mule JSON Logger to my Anypoint Exchange based from the following repo - https://github.com/mulesoft-consulting/json-logger

When the execute the deploy-to-exchange.sh script with the ORG ID provided I keep getting Java Build Failures with a huge stack trace.

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[WARNING] diagnostic: warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_8' from annotation processor 'org.mule.runtime.ast.internal.extension.loader.ASTExtensionResourcesGeneratorAnnotationProcessor' less than -source '20'
[INFO] diagnostic: Note: Starting Resources generator for Extensions
[ERROR] error on execute: use -X to have details 
[DEBUG] 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.invocationHelper (JavacTaskImpl.java:168)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall (JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call (JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
    at org.bsc.maven.plugin.processor.AbstractAnnotationProcessorMojo.executeWithExceptionsHandled (AbstractAnnotationProcessorMojo.java:778)
    at org.bsc.maven.plugin.processor.AbstractAnnotationProcessorMojo.execute (AbstractAnnotationProcessorMojo.java:429)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:827)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:272)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:195)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke ..........
```

I have JDK 20 installed on my machine but I was getting the same error even with JDK 8 which I had earlier. Any ideas what could be causing this issue?

Comment: Please share your pom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that it is related to using Java 20. Downgrade to Java 8 or [change the source level](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) to Java 8 in the pom.

```xml
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
```